# How to get number of occurences of items after certain item in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings like the one below, written in Python. What I want to do now is to get the number of occurences of the string 'you' after each string 'hello'. The output should then be something like the number 0 for the first two 'hello's , the number 2 for the third 'hello', number 1 for the fourth 'hello' and so on.

Does anyone know how to that exactly?

```
my_list = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'you', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 
           'you', 'you', 'you', ...]
```

**Update:**

Solved it myself, though Karan Elangovans approach also works:

This is how i did it:

```
list_counter = []
counter = 0

# I reverse the list because the loop below counts the number of 
# occurences of 'you' behind each 'hello', not in front of it
my_list_rev = reversed(my_list)

for m in my_list_rev:
    if m == 'you':
        counter += 1
    elif m == 'hello':
        list_counter.append(counter)
        counter = 0

# reverse the output to match it with my_list     
list_counter = list(reversed(list_counter))

print(list_counter)
```

This outputs:

```
[0, 0, 2, 1, 3]
```

for:

```
my_list = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'you', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 
           'you', 'you', 'you']
```

Maybe not the best approach, as you have to reverse both the original list and the list with the results to get the correct output, but it works for this problem.

Comment: Or try to code it just like you would do it if you were to explain the process to somebody else, and then edit your question to show us your try and get possible better answers.

Comment: @JohnColeman Not a homework. Just something I was curious on working on as I didn't want to count the number of occurences of 'you' after each 'hello' manually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one-liner:

```
reduce(lambda acc, cur: acc + ([] if cur[1] == 'you' else [next((i[0] - cur[0] - 1 for i in list(enumerate(my_list))[cur[0]+1:] if i[1] == 'hello'), len(my_list) - cur[0] - 1)]), enumerate(my_list), [])
```

It will give an array where the nth element is the number of 'you's following the nth occurrence of 'hello'.

e.g.
If `my_list = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'you', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'hello', 'you', 'you', 'you']`,

it will give: `[0, 0, 2, 1, 3]`

Comment: Thanks, I solved it myself, but your code also works just fine.